# Words break on line break with overflow

Tags: html, css

A style

```
#test {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    width: 99%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto; width: 50%;
}
```

Words in the div id="test" breaks like:

```
no  //this is end of first line
thing //this is beginning of the next line

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

the original word was `nothing`

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Use only  `white-space: nowrap;` to get the whole word without breaking. But I am sure that the white space cant be removed between `no` and `thing` unless you remove from the text and write it as `nothing`

```css
#test {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 99%;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto; width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="test">
  no 
thing
  </div>
</div>
```